# Windows 10 corrupting file system

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Win 10 Pro began inexplicably organizing file types into singular folders, then including them in `Libraries`:

- My preferred folder for personal files is `C:\JMB` and all files vanished from it, afterward noticing shadow copies of the Libraries where they are located are actually partitions, and I would arrive in them via Libary or file/folder redirection
- `C:\JMB` allows me to open a philosophy `.pdf`, but if I browse to `C:\JMB`, or view the file's *Properties*, Windows shows them on a virtual drive, with the original local disk not containing `C:\JMB` or `C:\JMB\Kant.pdf`

It appears permanent deletion happened, as everything is missing; worse, every PC and Mac on LAN suffered.

- I put a stop to virtual drives and redirection, killed Libraries, and administration alias. I now have twenty shadow volumes of every partition though, each one sharing the same drive letter, but with no similarities to the original filesystem structure

I know it's Win 10 because I installed it on a separate machine offline and it occurred again. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Restore from backups? I'd also recommend against keeping files in filesystem root on system drive. Use your user directory.

Comment: Also make certain your files are not in a One Drive folder as well. Files in folders truly not part of anything else should not be corrupted or deleted. My files (many GB of hem) are safely stored on my Windows 10 computers.

Comment: Win10, regardless of version, doesn't auto-organize files/folders in the method you describe by default and seems to have been caused by malware, especially if this occurs on multiple machines or after a reinstall. Download Windows install media from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) directly, however you're first going to want to run offline virus and malware scans on all devices affected first. _(Please use proper nomenclature, such as "Library folder(s)", not "Lib. Fx", and correct markdown for monospaced code)_

Comment: Yes, it was a Seagate Backup Slim ssd external usb drive that  supplied its own drivers and worked around no-autoplay by havint drivers install software located on a hidden volume on that drive. this software and driver is causing all the problems. It is exploiting Windows services such as Hyper-V, Library via Folder redirection, Link tracking across volumes and networks and frighteningly Web files as a single Gtp volume. I discovered this by using a shadow volume explorer and dozens of snapshots are made when it moves or deletes files, on all external media and all network devices attaches.